# Find the sum of the first and second derivative in one point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is three times differentiable and satisfies 
$$f(x^2)f''(x)=f'(x)f'(x^2)$$
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Under the condition $f(1) = 1$ and $f'''(1) = 8$ find the value of $f'(1) + f''(1)$.

Comment: I have improved your formating. Are you sure you mean that $f'''(x) = 8$ and not e.g. $f'''(1) = 8$?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is how you predicted  my bad

Comment: The question wasn't whether the value is $8$, but whether the equation is $f'''(x) = 8$ and not $f'''(1) = 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st step**: Plug in $x=1$ into the equation, you will get $f''(1)= f'(1)^2$;
**2nd step**: Take one more derivative on both sides, we will get $$2xf'(x^2)f''(x) + f(x^2)f'''(x)=f''(x)f'(x^2)+f'(x)f''(x^2)2x$$
The first term and last term cancels out, which leave following equation:
$$f(x^2)f'''(x)=f''(x)f'(x^2)$$
Plug in $x=1$, you will have $f'(1)=2$, consequently $f''(1)=4$.

Let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. From the identity evaluated at $1$, we have  $f''(1)=(f'(1))^2$.
Then differentiate both sides of the identity and evaluate it at $1$. 
You should find another relation between $f''(1)$ and $f'(1)$, namely
$f''(1)f'(1)=8$. Now it should be easy to find $f'(1)+f''(1)$.